# Slim application giving 500 error despite of enable debugging

Tags: php, slim

I am developing and application in slim framework. I have enabled debugging to true but whenever there is an error. It makes the application go into http 500 internal error occurred state but doesn't show me where the error actually happened and what causing it. How do I get to see the cause of error?

Here is my code:

```
require 'lib/vendor/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require 'lib/init.php';
require 'lib/Slim/Slim.php';

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

use lib\Slim\Middleware\SessionCookie;

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim([
    // cookie encryption (strongly recommend)
      'log.level' => \Slim\Log::DEBUG,
    'cookies.encrypt' => true,
    'cookies.secret_key' => 'put your secret key',
    // session config
    'sessions.driver' => 'database', // or database
    //'sessions.files' => __DIR__ . '/../sessions', // require mkdir
    'sessions.table' => 'sessions', // require create table#
      'debug' => true,
]);


$app->run();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Ensure you've configured your development box to display all error messages. If PHP code fails to run you cannot rely on Slim to report it to you.

Comment: Check your web-server log files. I have a feeling it'll be in there... I am guessing it has something to do with your use Session Cookie line.

Comment: should you not register the autoloader **before** you `use` something from the Slim framework?

Answer (score 0):

Fatal parsing errors are not shown on enabling debugging in slim. The configuration just enables an error handler for exceptions. So if one of your libraries throws an exception, slim renders them in an readable way for the web. On productions systems you want to disable debugging, cause a stack trace for the exception might reveal potential security leaks.

Looking in your code, I would suggest using https://getcomposer.org/ for auto loading and managing your libraries. It is certainly less work for managing Slim3 with its extensions.

For the 500er error, I guess your `use` is wrong. But a look into the error logs of your server should reveal the location of the error.

On the command line you can try `php -l filename.php` to find simple parsing errors.